# let curve $y=\dfrac{x^2}{4}$ and point $F(0,1)$. Let points $A_1(x_1,y_1),A_2(x_2,y_2),...,A_n(x_n,y_n)$ be n points on curve such that

Tags: limits, conic-sections

let curve $y=\dfrac{x^2}{4}$ and point $F(0,1)$. Let points $A_1(x_1,y_1),A_2(x_2,y_2),...,A_n(x_n,y_n)$ be n points on curve such that $x_k>0$ and $\angle{OFA_k}=\dfrac{k\pi}{2n}, (k=1,2,3....,n)$ then find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} FA_k$

I am not able to get how to solve. Can anyone help. Thanks

Comment: Standard way: 1. Write equation for line $FA_k$ using slope and point $F$. 2. Find coordinates of $A_k$ which is intersection of curve and line $FA_k$. 3. Find distance $FA_k$. 4. Find sum (this step can be very hard). 5. Find limit. But: If you draw the picture, you can see that $A_n \to O$ as $n\to\infty$. Then limit is $OF$ which is 1.

Comment: The seems to be $4/\pi$, not $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $A(a,a^2/4)$ a point on $f$ and $\varphi=\angle OFA$.  From
$$\tan(\varphi)=\frac{a}{1-a^2/4}\quad\text{and}\quad
\sin(\varphi)=\frac{a}{FA}$$
we get
$$FA=\frac{2}{1+\cos(\varphi)}.$$
From here
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{1+\cos(k\pi/2n)}&=
\frac{2}{\pi}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{1+\cos(k\pi/2n)}\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2}{1+\cos(x)}\,dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot2\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}.
\end{align}
$$